# C++: avoiding the "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have written a small class that implements a special thread safe queue that backups itself into a data base a few seconds after the last write into this queue (so if the queue is read before that the data base would be left alone).

I need several of these queues and at one point I need access to them all, so I had the idea of putting them into a `std::map` so I can access a single queue by its key and all of them with an iterator.
Unfortunately I get the "use of deleted function" error when trying to `insert()` a pair of a key and the according queue object. While looking up the meaning I have realised that the problem is probably my usage of `std::mutex` to make the queue thread-safe (an absolutely important requirement in my use case) and `std::mutex` is apparently non-movable and non-copyable.

So my question is: what do I have to do to put several instances of that class into a `std::map`? I mean, there is no real need to copy anything, I won't resize the map after populating it once at the start, I won't delete any object from it and the map has a life time from start of the application and until the machine reboots. The map itself is declared a static and I won't ever make any copies of this map, I just want to access the queues in a comfortable way and efficiency is a non-issue, only code readability.

Here is what the queue class looks like:

```
class QueueData
{
    public:
        QueueData(std::string table);
        long GetLastSync(void);
        void PushRecord(const std::string& msg);
        std::string PopRecord(void);
        void PopulateQueue(void);
        void DumpQueue(void);
        void Clear(void);
        size_t GetSize(void);
    private:
        std::string _table;
        std::deque<std::string> _queue;
        long _lastSync;
        std::mutex _mxqueue;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Well, the best way to avoid that error is not using deleted functions. (Hint: [mutexes aren't copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex))

Comment: I know that mutexes are not copyable, matter of fact I have written it into my question. Unfortunately I absolutely cannot avoid using a mutex.

Comment: Delete your auto generated copy constructor and assignment operator then. Or did you mean your class is copyable?

Comment: But... you don't need a copy of a mutex, just write the copy constructor and initialize a new mutex. If the mutex is locked, throw an exception. Also, change your title to something that better reflects what you want and format the giant wall of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move/copy a `std::mutex` and hence also not a `QueueData`. Instead, you must construct it in place, which is done via the `emplace()` member (supported for most STL containers since C++11).

```
std::map<key_type, QueueData> QueueMap;

QueueMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                 std::forward_as_tuple(key),
                 std::forward_as_tuple(table));

// with C++17, you can
QueueMap.try_emplace(key,table);   // C++17
```